# Weather Underground API to get historical data in Python

Tags: python, json, api, wunderground

I am trying to pull historical data from the Weather Underground API.  I adapted their Python example code (see below).  When I run this I get an exception "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"  The JSON stream includes a bunch of fields with daily summary information (Dailysummary), but I cannot get out and any of the values they have in this list.

I put the URL into a JSON viewer to look at the structure, and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib2
import json
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/d08c4738fb303c66/geolookup/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json')

json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
location = parsed_json['location']['city']
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print "Current temperature in %s is: %s" % (location, temp_f)
f.close()

h = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/d08c4738fb303c66/history_19760508/q/CA/San_Francisco.json')
json_string = h.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
date = parsed_json['history']['utcdate']['pretty']
print date

print type(parsed_json['history'])

snow = parsed_json['history']['dailysummary']['0']
print snow
h.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wunderground API to get hourly forecast returns error. - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572150/wunderground-api-to-get-hourly-forecast-returns-error-python)

Answer (score 2):

It says your problem right in the error: You can't index a list with a string:

```
>>> [1]['0']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>> [1][0]
1
>>>
```

But you do it here:

```
snow = parsed_json['history']['dailysummary']['0']
```

To fix your problem, make your indexes integers:

```
snow = parsed_json['history']['dailysummary'][0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Apologies as I am new to this.  All that is being returned is a list with all the variable keys and their values.  So this is a long list, but I want to pull specific values out for fog, maxdailytemp, etc.

Comment: @user2719147 - Then that isn't a list, but a dictionary.  And, to access a value in a dictionary, use it's corresponding key like so: `mydict[key]`

Comment: well, when i check the type I am getting it back as a list with only 1 value.  This is the whole problem otherwise I would grab the value without a problem.  I don't know where things went wrong.

Comment: Maybe I should propose the question in another way.  How can I get the daily summary values of fog, rain, snow, hail, thunder, etc from teh Weather Underground API?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Since it is a list of length 1, you can access the list item by the index 0. Now, if you check the type of the value item in index 0, it is a dictionary.

```
type(parsed_json['history']['dailysummary'][0])
<type 'dict'>
```

Now, that you know it is a dictionary, you can use keys to access the values. In your case.

```
print parsed_json['history']['dailysummary'][0]['snow']
```

This give you the value you are looking for.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way to access the contents in `parsed_json` dict is using the keys. You can find the keys you're interested in using `print parsed_json['history']['dailysummary'].keys()`

If you do that you'll see that one of the keys is `u'snow'` which is a unicode string.

You can use that string to access the data you're looking for so instead of:

`parsed_json['history']['dailysummary']['0']`

what you need is:

`parsed_json['history']['dailysummary']['snow']`